# TS/ESlint, preventing Map access with square brackets

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Using a `Map`, in the example below:

```
const m = new Map<number, string>();
m.set(1, 'one');
console.log(m.get(1)); // correct way to access the value residing at 1
console.log(m[1]); // incorrect - why is this allowed? how do I prevent this kind of usage?
```

Running the above code block produces the following output:

```
one
undefined
```

I'm curious, why is the square bracket access allowed by TS/ESLint? Shouldn't the compiler and/or linter know that a variable `m` of type `Map` will not respond to the square bracket accessor? Is there any way to configure TS or ESLint to warn/error for these types of incorrect usages (specifically when utilizing the `Map` type)?

Comment: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtjAvDMBTA7jAsgQwA4A8YArnAEaoBOANDNJQJZgDmAfABQCUA3AFBwA6CKijsAjLQDk4VJJ69QkEABtUA5SGbtBzEeM48YAeiMxQlSqmCx0OAJ4woIGDmDBUECI4AWqGADccZWI-SwgGABMmZhdYMQVwCBU1DS04AG0xAF1DExgmc0trGABaGHRvBwYvKG9ql2UNdFQIgH4YbxBMCOcASRg8S39UMFha+oBrJgiYEAAzGGIIHF1W3iA) gives the error "*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Map<number, string>' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'm.get'?(7052)*" so it's not. Unless your TSconfig has looser settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not allowed. If you set up a TypeScript project with the default configuration, you will get a compile time error when trying to access a property via indexed access if the property does not exist.

```
const m = new Map<number, string>();
console.log(m[1]);
//          ^^^^ Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 
//               'Map<number, string>' has no index signature
```

Particularly responsible for this error is the `noImplictAny` rule which is included in the [`strict` suite](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) of compiler flags. Accessing property `1` of a `Map` which does not have a numeric index signature would result in a value of type `any` triggering the error.

Please note that accessing properties with the bracket notation effectively bypasses the usual property access rules. It is allowed to use this notation to access properties that a type might not have. But the result *implicitly* being of type `any` is triggering the error.